# FRC problem with getting to run a motor for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, robotics

So I'm trying to have the code run the motor for a certain amount of time based on what the REV color sensor V3 senses. I've tried many things. but in the end it just gets stuck in an infinite loop.
I don't know how to fix this thing I don't know if there is a way to do this rather then what I'm trying to do.

```
private void redDetect(){
  long t= System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (buttons[9]){
    long endg = t+15000; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endg) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (buttons[10]){
    long endy = t+10000; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endy) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      break;
    }
  }
    if (buttons[11]){
      long endr = t+7000; 
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endr) {
        trenchMotor.set(0.6);
        break;
      }
    }
      if (buttons[12]){
        long endb = t+5000; 
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endb) {
          trenchMotor.set(0.6);
          break;
        }
    } 
} 

private void blueDetect(){
  long t= System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (buttons[9]){
    long endg = t+15000; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endg) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (buttons[10]){
    long endy = t+10000; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endy) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      break;
    }
  }
    if (buttons[11]){
      long endr = t+7000; 
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endr) {
        trenchMotor.set(0.6);
        break;
      }
    }
      if (buttons[12]){
        long endb = t+5000; 
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endb) {
          trenchMotor.set(0.6);
          break;
        }
    } 
} 

private void greenDetect(){
int endg = 10;

  if (buttons[9]){
    while (endg > 0) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      endg --; 

      break;
    }
  }
  if (buttons[10]){
    int endy = 1000;
    while (endy > 0) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      endy--;
      break;
    }
  }
    if (buttons[11]){
      int endr = 7000; 
      while (endr > 0) {
        trenchMotor.set(0.6);
        endr--;
        break;
      }
    }
      if (buttons[12]){
        int endb = 5000; 
        while (endb > 0) {
          trenchMotor.set(0.6);
          endb--;
          break;
        }
    } 
} 

private void yellowDetect(){
  long t= System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (buttons[9]){
    long endg = t+15000; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endg) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (buttons[10]){
    long endy = t+10000; 
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endy) {
      trenchMotor.set(0.6);
      break;
    }
  }
    if (buttons[11]){
      long endr = t+7000; 
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endr) {
        trenchMotor.set(0.6);
        break;
      }
    }
      if (buttons[12]){
        long endb = t+5000; 
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endb) {
          trenchMotor.set(0.6);
          break;
        }
    } 
}
```

```
if(detectedColor.red > detectedColor.green && detectedColor.red > detectedColor.blue) {
      redDetect();
    }

    if(detectedColor.blue > detectedColor.green && detectedColor.blue > detectedColor.red) {
      blueDetect();
    }

    if(detectedColor.green > detectedColor.blue && detectedColor.green > detectedColor.red) {
      greenDetect();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `trenchMotor()` in a loop that you terminate (break) always after its first execution???

Comment: I've removed the breaks

Comment: Hello Arda. Consider updating the code you posted to reflect the modifications you made. 
Also, could you explain what the "buttons" array used in your conditions is about?